# Como utilizar funções Jquery em array?

Tags: jquery

Estou selecionando um *select* e tentando por meio do array acessar uma das *options* para coloca-la com o atributo *selected*, porém sempre que tento utilizar o `.att("selected", "selected");` recebo o erro: `TypeError: size[0][1].attr is not a function`

Select:

```
<select id="size" name="size" class="selectpicker" data-title="Tamanho" data-style="btn-default btn-block" data-menu-style="dropdown-blue">
      <option value="PP" >PP</option>
      <option value="P">P</option>
      <option value="M">M</option>
      <option value="G">G</option>
      <option value="GG">GG</option>
      <option value="XGG">XGG</option>
      <option value="XXXG">XXXGG</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
var size = $("#size");
size[0][1].attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Erro:

```
TypeError: size[0][1].attr is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `.get()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var size = $("#size");
  var index = 1  //seu 1;
  $(size.find('option').get(index)).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="size" name="size" class="selectpicker" data-title="Tamanho" data-style="btn-default btn-block" data-menu-style="dropdown-blue">
      <option value="PP" >PP</option>
      <option value="P">P</option>
      <option value="M">M</option>
      <option value="G">G</option>
      <option value="GG">GG</option>
      <option value="XGG">XGG</option>
      <option value="XXXG">XXXGG</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oque seria o index?

Comment: Seria a posição do option que você gostaria de selecionar, o que você pretendia com `$(size[0][1]).attr('selected', 'selected');` ?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está usando `.attr` para alterar o atributo do objeto não jQuery. Os objetos jQuery devem estar dentro de `$()`.

Se você quer usar JavaScript puro, teria que usar `.setAttribute`:

```
var size = $("#size");
size[0][1].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
```

Ou converter o `size` para um objeto jQuery e usar `.attr`:

```
var size = $("#size");
$(size[0][1]).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Ou você pode colocar o `[0]` direto na variável:

```
size = $("#size")[0];
size[1].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
```